# Calculating a bounding box for Windows Forms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, grouping, bounding-box

I have a project for university using Windows Forms. I have a base Shape class with my base properties. I have an `EllipseShape` class with properties specific for ellipse and a `RectangleShape` class with properities for triangle. I have to create `GroupShape` class which has to group the selected items for the purpose of group manipulations like rotating or moving etc.

Here's my base Shape class:

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    #region Constructors
    
    public Shape()
    {
    }
    
    public Shape(RectangleF rect)
    {
        rectangle = rect;
    }
    
    public Shape(Shape shape)
    {
        this.Height = shape.Height;
        this.Width = shape.Width;
        this.Location = shape.Location;
        this.rectangle = shape.rectangle;
        
        this.FillColor =  shape.FillColor;
    }
    #endregion      
    #region Properties      
    
    private RectangleF rectangle;       
    public virtual RectangleF Rectangle {
        get { return rectangle; }
        set { rectangle = value; }
    }
    
    
    public virtual float Width {
        get { return Rectangle.Width; }
        set { rectangle.Width = value; }
    }
    
    public virtual float Height {
        get { return Rectangle.Height; }
        set { rectangle.Height = value; }
    }

    public virtual PointF Location {
        get { return Rectangle.Location; }
        set { rectangle.Location = value; }
    }

    private Color fillColor;        
    public virtual Color FillColor {
        get { return fillColor; }
        set { fillColor = value; }
    }


    private Color strokeColor;
    public virtual Color StrokeColor
    {
        get { return strokeColor; }
        set { strokeColor = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    public virtual bool Contains(PointF point)
    {
        return Rectangle.Contains(point.X, point.Y);
    }

    public virtual void DrawSelf(Graphics grfx)
    {
        // shape.Rectangle.Inflate(shape.BorderWidth, shape.BorderWidth);
    }
    
}
```

My `EllipseShape` Class:

```
public class EllipseShape : Shape
{
    #region Constructor

    public EllipseShape(RectangleF rect) : base(rect)
    {
    }

    public EllipseShape(RectangleShape rectangle) : base(rectangle)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    static int checkpoint(float h, float k, float x,
              float y, float a, float b)
    {

        // checking the equation of
        // ellipse with the given point
        int p = ((int)Math.Pow((x - h), 2) /
                 (int)Math.Pow(a, 2)) +
                ((int)Math.Pow((y - k), 2) /
                 (int)Math.Pow(b, 2));

        return p;
    }

    public override bool Contains(PointF point)
    {
        float h = Rectangle.X + 50;
        float k = Rectangle.Y + 100;
        float a = (Rectangle.Width / 2);
        float b = (Rectangle.Height / 2);
        float x = point.X;
        float y = point.Y;

        if (checkpoint(h, k, x, y, a, b) > 1)
            return false;

        else if (checkpoint(h, k, x, y, a, b) == 1)
            return true;

        else
           return true;        
    }

    public override void DrawSelf(Graphics grfx)
    {
        base.DrawSelf(grfx);

        grfx.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(FillColor), Rectangle.X, Rectangle.Y, Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Height);
        grfx.DrawEllipse(new Pen(StrokeColor), Rectangle.X, Rectangle.Y, Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Height);

    }
}
```

My `RectangleShape` Class:

```
public class RectangleShape : Shape
{
    #region Constructor
    
    public RectangleShape(RectangleF rect) : base(rect)
    {
    }
    
    public RectangleShape(RectangleShape rectangle) : base(rectangle)
    {
    }
    
    #endregion

    public override bool Contains(PointF point)
    {
        if (base.Contains(point))

            return false;
    }
    public override void DrawSelf(Graphics grfx)
    {
        base.DrawSelf(grfx);
        
        grfx.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(FillColor),Rectangle.X, Rectangle.Y, Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Height);
        grfx.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,Rectangle.X, Rectangle.Y, Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Height);
        
    }
}
```

This is part my class which handels the processes:

```
    public void AddRandomRectangle()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int x = rnd.Next(100,1000);
        int y = rnd.Next(100,600);
        
        RectangleShape rect = new RectangleShape(new Rectangle(x,y,100,200));
        rect.FillColor = Color.White;

        ShapeList.Add(rect);
    }

    
    public void AddRandomEllipse()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int x = rnd.Next(100, 1000);
        int y = rnd.Next(100, 600);

        EllipseShape ellipse = new EllipseShape(new Rectangle(x, y, 100, 200));
        ellipse.FillColor = Color.White;
        ellipse.StrokeColor = Color.Blue;

        ShapeList.Add(ellipse);


    }

    
    public Shape ContainsPoint(PointF point)
    {
        for(int i = ShapeList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            if (ShapeList[i].Contains(point)){
                ShapeList[i].FillColor = Color.Red;
                    
                return ShapeList[i];
            }   
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And this is the part of the MainForm I haven't filled yet:

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dialogProcessor.AddRandomEllipse();

    statusBar.Items[0].Text = "";

    viewPort.Invalidate();
}

private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Shape item in dialogProcessor.Selection)
    {
        if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            item.FillColor = colorDialog1.Color;
            viewPort.Invalidate(); 
        }
    }
}


private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //calculate bounding box
    //new group shape
}
```

I need help with the creating of `GroupShape` class and the `toolStripButton3_Click`.

Comment: Where is an attempt to make `GroupShape`? Bounding box calculation is not just a hit test (your `Figure.Contains` method), you will need to extend `Figure` to give you each figure bounds somehow. Then iterating collection of figures to get combined bounds shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: " I have to create GroupShape class which has to group the selected items" you need to clarify (even for yourself) what **grouping** exactly means here. If you can answer this question, the rest should unfold itself.

Comment: _"and a **Rectangle**Shape class with properities for **triangle**."_ - Really?